# Rails: I installed Ruby, now "bundle install" doesn't work

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, installation, bundle

I’m using Rails 4.2.7.  I downloaded an example that evidently requires me to use Ruby 2.1.6 rather than the Ruby 2.3.0 version I had installed …

```
localhost:lti_tool_provider_example-master davea$ bundle install
Your Ruby version is 2.3.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.6
```

So that’s what I did.  However after installing Ruby 2.1.6, now “bundle install” doesn’t work …

```
localhost:lti_tool_provider_example-master davea$ rvm install ruby-2.1.6
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin' is not at first place,
         usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries,
         it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles',
         to fix temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-2.3.0'.
Warning, new version of rvm available '1.27.0', you are using older version '1.26.11'.
You can disable this warning with:    echo rvm_autoupdate_flag=0 >> ~/.rvmrc
You can enable  auto-update  with:    echo rvm_autoupdate_flag=2 >> ~/.rvmrc
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
Found remote file https://rubies.travis-ci.org/osx/10.12/x86_64/ruby-2.1.6.tar.bz2
Checking requirements for osx.
Certificates in '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem' are already up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
ruby-2.1.6 - #configure
ruby-2.1.6 - #download
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100 7630k  100 7630k    0     0  1199k      0  0:00:06  0:00:06 --:--:-- 1551k
No checksum for downloaded archive, recording checksum in user configuration.
ruby-2.1.6 - #validate archive
ruby-2.1.6 - #extract
ruby-2.1.6 - #validate binary
Libraries missing for ruby-2.1.6: cannot. Refer to your system manual for installing libraries
Mounting remote ruby failed with status 10, trying to compile.
Checking requirements for osx.
Certificates in '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem' are already up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
Warning: DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable is set, this might interact with the compilation and ruby.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.6, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.1.6 - #downloading ruby-2.1.6, this may take a while depending on your connection...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 11.4M  100 11.4M    0     0  2272k      0  0:00:05  0:00:05 --:--:-- 2354k
No checksum for downloaded archive, recording checksum in user configuration.
ruby-2.1.6 - #extracting ruby-2.1.6 to /Users/davea/.rvm/src/ruby-2.1.6....
ruby-2.1.6 - #configuring....................................................
ruby-2.1.6 - #post-configuration.
ruby-2.1.6 -    #compiling.......................................................................................................................................
ruby-2.1.6 - #installing...............
ruby-2.1.6 - #making binaries executable..
ruby-2.1.6 - #downloading rubygems-2.4.8
ruby-2.1.6 - #extracting rubygems-2.4.8.....
ruby-2.1.6 - #removing old rubygems.........
ruby-2.1.6 - #installing rubygems-2.4.8......................
ruby-2.1.6 - #gemset created /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@global
ruby-2.1.6 - #importing gemset /Users/davea/.rvm/gemsets/global.gems...............................................
ruby-2.1.6 - #generating global wrappers........
ruby-2.1.6 - #gemset created /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6
ruby-2.1.6 - #importing gemsetfile /Users/davea/.rvm/gemsets/default.gems evaluated to empty gem list
ruby-2.1.6 - #generating default wrappers........
ruby-2.1.6 - #adjusting #shebangs for (gem irb erb ri rdoc testrb rake).
Install of ruby-2.1.6 - #complete 
Ruby was built without documentation, to build it run: rvm docs generate-ri
localhost:lti_tool_provider_example-master davea$ bundle install
-bash: bundle: command not found
```

How do I restore the “bundle” command without interfering with the Ruby 2.1.3 version I just installed?

Comment: You could also have deleted the line specifying the Ruby version in Gemfile, and see if it works fine with your version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Bundle with Ruby 2.1.6

You just need to install [bundler](http://bundler.io/) :

```
rvm use ruby-2.1.6
gem install bundler
```

This will be installed in a gemset specific to ruby-2.1.6, so it won't interfere with anything you installed with ruby-2.3.0. You can use

```
bundle install
```

to install the required gems.

## Trying with Ruby 2.3.0

Alternatively, you could just try the example you downloaded with ruby-2.3.0 by either changing the

```
ruby '2.1.6'
```

line or deleting it from the `Gemfile`.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced this same issue. For my case, the cause of the issue was because of two conflicting versions of the **bundler gem** that are very close in version number.

```
bundler (2.0.2, 2.0.1, default: 1.17.2)
```

The issue was from the bundler versions 2.0.2 and version 2.0.1

**This is what I did to fix it.**

Open your terminal or command line

```
Ctrl + Alt + T
```

**N/B:** The command above is for Linux Users, the one for Windows users might be different

Display a list of all your local gems for the bundler gem

```
gem list bundler
```

**N/B:** The command above is for rbenv version manager, the one for rvm might be different

Look through the displayed versions of the bundler gem, you will see some closely related conflicting versions like the one below

```
bundler (2.0.2, 2.0.1, default: 1.17.2)
```

Uninstall the bundler gem

```
gem uninstall bundler
```

Install a new copy of the bundler gem

```
gem install bundler
```

Try running the bundle install command again now

```
bundle install
```

That's all

**I hope this helps.**

Answer (score 1):

Simply do the following

1. Open your terminal
2. Run **gem uninstall bundler** to uninstall previous versions of bundler
3. And then run **gem install bundler** to install a new copy of bundler

You can now run

```
bundle install
```

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, you must re-install bundler `gem` again (because last one was and actually is attached to the previous version you had, as global library, you could actually go back and set it up as default again and see that bundler still there since usually all ruby versions you install thru version managers `rbenv` or `rvm` will be kept locally in your machine user's folder.

Step by step run the following (just in case)

1. `rvm list known`
2. Let's say `ruby-2.3.3` is the latest or the one you want to work with
3. `rvm install ruby-2.3.3`
4. `rvm use --default 2.3.3`
5. `gem install bundler`
6. `bundle install`

In my case i was using OSX also `rvm` in OSX rvm store rubies in `/Users/some_user/.rvm/rubies/default` so just remember to configure whatever your terminal is with the proper rvm's ruby path in this case the file i should double check will be `.bash_profile` and the line of code i would look for will be `export PATH=$PATH:/Users/some_user/.rvm/rubies/default`

Hope this is helpful for someone that just realizes how `rvm` and `rbenv` work around, i was expecting somehow that `bundler` being a *key* part of the process will be more like a `core library` per se (ruby), but instead `bundler` is a totally separated `gem`, which bring me back to think, what a gem! way to go! inspirational one!